# Dynatree expansion of node

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I have a dynatree with

```
  selectMode: 2,
```

When I expand a node with my mouse after clicking [+] on a node, the node is expanded but also selected. I dont want it to be selected, how can I do that?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you sure it's getting selected or just focused. On a stock tree with selectMode equal to 2, when expanding a node, it gets focused, not selected. Anyways, try autoFocus: false,

Comment: Yes, it selects the nodes. I get the expanded node when I use the getSelectedNodes function

Comment: The same happens in the last example of the page
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-select.html